# Kendo UI dropdown performance issue when it has more data

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I am using Kendo UI dropdown with angular, but it is very slow when I have huge data. To overcome this problem, is it possible to load data dynamically like when we reach the last element in the drop down, the component should load next 500 records etc.
my code looks like this.

```
<kendo-dropdownlist [data]="issues" style="width: 100%;" [popupSettings]="{ width: 'auto' }">
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

what I am expecting is the same behaviour which shows in this example:(With Infinite scroll)

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/OwhFCyHz0mO1yZMj5UW5?p=preview
```

Please let me know whether we can expect same behaviour with kendo dropdownlist component?
Thanks.

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/virtualization

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can apply Kendo Virtualization.

See example below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    

</head>
<body>

        <div id="example">

            <div class="demo-section k-content">
                <h4>Orders</h4>
                <input id="orders" style="width: 100%" />
            </div>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#orders").kendoComboBox({
                        template: '<span class="order-id">#= OrderID #</span> #= ShipName #, #= ShipCountry #',
                        dataTextField: "ShipName",
                        dataValueField: "OrderID",
                        virtual: {
                            itemHeight: 26,
                            valueMapper: function(options) {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Orders/ValueMapper",
                                    type: "GET",
                                    dataType: "jsonp",
                                    data: convertValues(options.value),
                                    success: function (data) {
                                        options.success(data);
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                        },
                        height: 290,
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "odata",
                            transport: {
                                read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
                            },
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    fields: {
                                        OrderID: { type: "number" },
                                        Freight: { type: "number" },
                                        ShipName: { type: "string" },
                                        OrderDate: { type: "date" },
                                        ShipCity: { type: "string" }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            pageSize: 80,
                            serverPaging: true,
                            serverFiltering: true
                        }
                    });
                });

                function convertValues(value) {
                    var data = {};

                    value = $.isArray(value) ? value : [value];

                    for (var idx = 0; idx < value.length; idx++) {
                        data["values[" + idx + "]"] = value[idx];
                    }

                    return data;
                }
            </script>

        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a copy from the link I posted as a comment. However the OP is working with angular, not the jquery plugin syntax. An angular example would be a better answer here.

Comment: Thanks NigeIK. Any solution in angular?

Comment: Sorry, I've no experience with angular. It almost certainly can work in angular but you may need to visit the telerik forums if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

DropDowns virtualization is currently not supported in Kendo UI for Angular, but you can improve performance by utilizing the filtering functionality of the dropdowns along with a minimum filter length, thus decreasing the number of rendered elements:

[Docs and example](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/filtering/)

You can also support the following feature request:

[Feature request](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/555517-kendo-ui-for-angular-feedback/suggestions/31559278-dropdownlist-virtualization)